# Repartitioning Linux mint installation

Tags: linux, partitioning, linux-mint

i have a 128GB SSD with linux installed on it( was originally windows)
i installed windows on my HDD afterwards, but now windows freaks out about that and always shows 100% disk usage (windows problem/bug?) with a fresh installation.

now to speed windows up and make it work better i wanted to partition the SSD to fit windows in, the problem i am encountering at the moment is that i cannot resize my /dev/sda2 partition

[image]

is there any way to get around this?,

i also thought about changing linux to the HDD and windows to the SSD completely, but i cant really afford to lose the data on the linux system as it is where i do my coding work on. and backing everything up isnt really that much of an option. unless it would be the only way to be able to install linux and windows both on the SSD, but before i do that i really need some help to try and find a safe way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not resize a mounted filesystem. You're probably running GParted directly from Linux (Mint). That "vault icon" next to partition name should mean that it's locked for modification (but it's not very intuitive I guess).

Download some [live USB (CD) image](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php) and boot from it.

**NOTE:** When resizing partitions it's **ALWAYS strongly recommended** to backup all data on that drive.

Comment: ahh okay thank you, i will try that option :)

Comment: Just as addition in your answer (it worked great btw!) i ran into another problem not being able to boot the live usb : if you encounter hangs while booting try using nouveau.modeset=0 in the grub bootloader :D that worked for me anyway and i think more people will encounter this